# p:dataTable with p:rowExpansion with p:selectBooleanCheckbox along with pagination has weird behavior

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My requirement is to show checkbox inside a `p:rowexapansion` of a `p:datatable` in PrimeFaces 5.2

Problem:

All the boolean attributes for the entities in the list for which the datatable is referring become false when I use with along with pagination

Steps to reproduce:

1. Try to use the prime faces rowExpansion from PrimeFaces showcase
2. Place selectBooleanCheckbox which shows the boolean value
3. Access the pagination of the datatable
4. See that for all the entries in the list the boolean attribute become false, also I tried to print the datatable in the managed bean, the data in the list also got modified, it is bit weird that with row expansion the data in list is being modified
5. When I test the same feature with rowExpansion and without selectBooleanCheckbox everything works normally

[data_after_row_exapantion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA84a.png)

[data_modifed_auto_after_row_exapantion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKoYZ.png)

Comment: what is the scope of your bean? try with view or sessionscoped

Comment: Better yet, post an [mcve], see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I have the same problem in PrimeFaces 5.2. It appears even without pagination and it doesn't matter if i use 'p:selectBooleanCheckbox' or 'h:selectBooleanCheckbox'... seems like a bug for me. Do you already solved it @Prateep?